# Как задать фон больше чем ширина родительского блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, background

Есть блок с контентом обернутый в container. И у него есть фоновый цвет который должен идти на всю ширину body(т.е. больше чем ширина контейнера-родителя). Как можно это сделать?

Comment: как вариант - перести  контейнер-родитель в блоки https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/mj5Le8bs/1/

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Родительскому блоку задал

```
  .container {  
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью единиц вьюпорта и функции `calc()`. А именно, блоку, который необходимо растянуть, надо задать ширину 100vw и сдвинуть его влево по формуле 
`(100vw - ширина_главного_контейнера) / -2`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc((100vw - 400px) / -2);
}

.container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  width: calc(400px - 2em);
}

.container p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <div class=container>
      <p>هناك حقيقة مثبتة منذ زمن طويل وهي أن المحتوى المقروء لصفحة ما سيلهي القارئ عن التركيز على الشكل الخارجي للنص أو شكل توضع الفقرات في الصفحة التي يقرأها. ولذلك يتم استخدام </p>
    </div>
  </header>
</main>
```